# Nginx and Apache virtual host for PunBB

Tags: apache, nginx, punbb

After copying the forum to another host the Login doesn't work.
I suppose that the problem comes from the way I set the virtual host.

Nginx proxy:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    location /forum/ {
        rewrite  ^/forum/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6666;
        ...
    }
}
```

Apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:6666>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /my/web/dir/forum

    <Directory /my/web/dir/forum>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . rewrite.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

config.php

```
$base_url = 'https://example.com/forum';
```

This was the only way I succeed at least to show the forum. However, the login and probably other stuff doesn't work.

When I try to log in, the "Confirm action" appears with wrong links in the form.

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.com/login/">
    <div class="hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="prev_url" value="https://example.com/login/">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="https://example.com/">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

The correct links are `https://example.com/forum/login`

How to solve the problem or to make the virtual hosting in a better way?

**Edit:**

On the old hosting the `.htaccess` has `RewriteBase /forum`, however with it, the forum doesn't work here. If I remove `rewrite  ^/forum/(.*) /$1 break;`, it gives "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error."

Comment: What is `rewrite  ^/forum/(.*) /$1 break;` rewrite rule for? Try what happens without it.

Comment: This is something very questionable. However, without it, it rises `circular reference`  (or similar) 10 times a termination of the request. I agree it would look better without it and `RewriteBase /forum` as in the old hosting.